# Migrate WCF service from IIS to self host. How and should I?

Tags: wcf

I'm currently hosting a WCF service on an IIS 7.5.

Problem is I need to save data for the duration of the session (using static members) but the AppPool recycle keeps deleting all the cached data.

For my understanding my only solution is to self host the service. 
I have no clue on how to do that and what are the pros and cons. 
is this really my only option?

**UPDATE**

Looks like there was a different problem.
I changed hosting from IIS to self-hosting on a console application and I found a bug that was crashing the app. I'm guessing this was the reason for the loss of data and not the app pool recycling...

Comment: depends on several things... does your service use a DB ? how does the app recycling and the session management work (recycling the app pool also looses all sessions, not only the cached data) ?

Comment: I do use a DB to retrieve and save data. Yes I loose everything when the app pool recycle...

Comment: why not use the DB as a cache ? how is your session management implemented ?

Comment: The DB only stores some of the data. Not all of it - and it's a lot of data. I can't really store everything on the db.

Comment: I created a session class. All the session classes are stored in a singleton class.

Comment: that doesn't give me much to go on... do you use the session management of WCF ?

Comment: No. I build e everything there.

Comment: Why are you not using the session management of WCF?

Comment: I'm actually not aware of it. Will it help me to save the cached data? How is it being used?

Answer (score 2):

That does not seem like a good reason to migrate from IIS to Windows service . why not to disable app Pool recycling by

> Idle Time-out(minutes) = 0
>
> "Regular time Interval(minutes)" = 0

so it will never recycle

Also

> `Disable Recycling for configuration Changes = true`

these settings live in advanced settings of AppPool

**Update: how about**

> "Disable Overlapped Recycle" = true

AppPool Recycle settings [image]

Comment: ok right click your app pool select pool recycling settings and untick everything eg memory based , number of requests and then untick everything on next page as well

Comment: Already done all that... Doesn't help... I don't know I'd it's the AppPool or not, but something causes me to lose all of my cached data...

Comment: just to make sure it is not recycling any more enable Pool's  event writing from "Generate Recycle Event Log Entry" in "Advanced Settings"

Comment: Check this post http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.applicationHost/applicationPools/add/recycling

Comment: Also this post http://blogs.msdn.com/b/david.wang/archive/2006/02/28/why-iis6-application-pool-recycle-events-are-not-logged.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If this is the problem, I think you are storing the cache in memory. We can store the store the cache in disk,database or any your customized location. so there is no need move your application from IIS to self-host.

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/01/27/extensible-output-caching-with-asp-net-4-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx